# How to use a CSV file which does not have any header in dataweave?

Tags: mule

I have a CSV file which is not having Headers.
I want to use this CSV file, use the values of each column and transform into another CSV with headers.
Is there any way to use Column positions of CSV in dataweave to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can read a CSV with no header values.

Here is how your dataweave code could be. Note the input-payload configuration which sets the header=false on reader.

```
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload>
                <dw:reader-property name="header" value="false"/>
            </dw:input-payload>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%input payload application/csv
%output application/csv
---
payload map {
    Id: $[0],
    TestCol1: $[1],
    TestCol2:$[2]
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

HTH.