# In DataWeave reading CSV with header=false causes the missing first line in the output

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-component, mule-esb

In DataWeave reading CSV with header=false causes the missing first line in the output how to fix in dataWeave 1.0

Comment: How are you reading it? can you share your dataweave that you are trying?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a CSV file which does not have any header in dataweave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213737/how-to-use-a-csv-file-which-does-not-have-any-header-in-dataweave)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not setting the reader property header correctly. DataWeave seems to assume it is the header line and doesn't uses it as the first record.